# Another arraylist to another arraylist of different type

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

```
public class Game {

    private ArrayList<Player> players;
    private ArrayList<Card> deck;
    private ArrayList<Card> pool;
    **private ArrayList<Capture> capture;**
    private int currentPlayer;
    private int playDirection;
    int index;
    int count = 0;
    int passNo = 0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input3 = new Scanner(System.in);

    public Game()
    {
        deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
        pool = new ArrayList<Card>();
        capture = new ArrayList<Capture>();

        for(int c=0; c<4; c++){
            for(int i=0; i<13; i++){
                deck.add(new Card(c,i));
            }
            Collections.shuffle(deck);
        }   

    }       

     public Player play() {
         Player player = getCurrentPlayer();
         int pass = -1;
         int option =0;
         int count =0;
         boolean play = false;
         boolean check = true;

         capture = new ArrayList<Capture>();

         System.out.println();
         System.out.println(player + ":" + player.getCards());

         do{
             System.out.println("Please select an option: ((1) Capture (2) Discard a card)");
             option = input2.nextInt();


             play=player.isPlayable();


             switch(option)
             {
             case 1:
                 if(play == true){

                     System.out.print("HandCard:" + player.getCards());
                     System.out.print("  Choose a Number from 0 to " + (player.getCards().size()-1)+ "  :   ");
                     int num = input.nextInt();
                     player.getCards().remove(num);
                  //after prompting user for entering the cards they wanted
                  //the following sentence has following error                                                          
                     **capture.add(player.getCards().get(num));**
                   //"The method add(Capture) in the type ArrayList<Capture> is  
                    //not applicable for the arguments (Card)"  
                    System.out.print("How many card you want capture from pool: (Choose 1 number from  1 to " + pool.size()+ ")" + "  :  ");
                    option = input.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Please choose your card in the pool:");
                    System.out.println("Pool");
                    for(int j=0; j<pool.size(); j++)
                    {
                        System.out.print("(" + j + ")" + pool.get(j) + " ");
                    }

                    for(int i=0; i<option;i++)
                    {

                            count = input.nextInt();
                            System.out.print(pool.get(count) + " ");
                            pool.remove(count);
                            //same problem as the above error
                            **capture.add(pool.get(count));**
                    }

                    System.out.print(player.getCards().get(num) + "  is selected");
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("=================================================");
                    check=false;
                 }
                 else
                     System.out.println("Invalid Capture, Please choose either (1) Capture or (2) Discard a Card");
                 break;

             case 2:
                 if(play == true){
                     Card discard = player.cardDiscard();
                     System.out.println(discard + " has been added to pool");
                     pool.add(discard);
                     player.removeCard(discard);
                     check=false;
                 }
                 else
                     System.out.println("Invalid Capture Please choose either (1) Capture or (2) Discard a Card");
                 break;

                 default:
                     System.out.println("Invalid option choose");

             }
         }while(check);

         if(pass==currentPlayer)
         {
             passNo++;
         }
         else{
             passNo = 0;
         }

         if(player.getCards().size() == 0 ){
             int i = 1;
             int [] point = new int[players.size()+1];
             point[0] = 100;
             int lowest = 0;
             System.out.println();

             for(Player p : players){
                 System.out.println(p + ":" + p.getTotalScores() + " points");
                 point[i] = p.getTotalScores();

                 if(point[i] < point[i-1]){
                     lowest = point[i];
                 }
                 i++;
             }
             for(Player p:players){
                 if(p.getTotalScores()==lowest)
                 {
                     player = p;
                 }
             }
             return player;
             }

         goToNextPlayer();
         System.out.println();
         System.out.println("=========================================================================");
         System.out.println("Pool"); 
         for(int i=0; i<pool.size(); i++)
            System.out.print("(" + i + ")" + pool.get(i) + " ");
            return null;
         }
```

//Capture Class
         import java.util.ArrayList;

```
       public abstract class Capture {
              private static ArrayList<Capture> capture;
              private static ArrayList<Card> card;
              boolean result = false;


public Capture()
{
    // leave bank 
}


// this part is the functions that hv to implement in pair , run , combo class
public abstract boolean formCapture(ArrayList<Capture> c);
public abstract double getScore();


public abstract void showMessage();}
```

Sorry for the long post but my problem lies on the parts commented, the errors appear making me unable to add the player hand cards and pool cards into the `ArrayList<Capture> Capture` list, but this list cannot be removed as it is being used in another class to detect other features used by other subclass. How do I solve the error and add the arraylist capture into a new type array list?
**Edited, Capture class has been added but not complete yet

Comment: What's the relationship between `Capture` and `Card`?

Comment: you can only add List <Capture> with Capture members functions.

Comment: Do you want to add Card descendats to ArrayList<Capture>? Does capture descendant of Capture as well? Because you can just add so objects into gerneric lists that type conform (they have common ancestor or common interface) to the list item type.

Comment: Please give the code for the Capture class

Comment: did not give you the needed information any of the answers?

Answer (score 0):

```
capture.add(player.getCards().get(num));
```

In this line

```
player.getCards().get(num)
```

is returning a Card object reference.
But you decleared the Arraylist as

```
private ArrayList<Capture> capture;
```

So

```
capture.add();
```

this method can only take a Capture Object reference as parameter or any object reference that may have same parent as Capture. where as you are providing it a Card Object reference And I am assuming it Card does not have the same ancestor or implements from the same interface as Capture. That is why it is giving you that error.

Comment: you can add another types too. just they should be type conform (they have common ancestor or interface) to the list item type

Comment: As he did not give his full code so I am assuming that Cards and Capture does not have same ancestor or interface. As he mentioned the Error shows "The method add(Capture) in the type ArrayList<Capture> is  not applicable for the arguments (Card)"  I think they do not have same parent

Comment: yes it true. but you wrote he can just add object of type Capture. it is closes the door in from of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Make an Interface let's say CardAndCapture and your Card and Capture class should implement this interface. Now in your code, change this line

capture = new ArrayList();

into

capture = new ArrayList();

Now your code should compile and run. You are making Card and Capture siblings here. So, make sure to properly integrate with CardCapture interface.

Answer (score 0):

If Capture has Card as instance variable like this:

```
 public class Capture{
    private Card card;

    public Capture(Card card){
       this.card = card;
    }
   ...
 }
```

**Usage**

```
 capture.add(new Capture(player.getCards().get(num)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Store object in a common list just if they have common usage. If they have common usage then partition this functionality into an interface and implement this interface by the classes intended to handle in the same manner. Create a generic list with this interface type and do method calls on the interfaces:

```
public interface ICommonUsage
{
  public void foo();
  public void bar();
}

public class Class1 implements ICommonUsage
{
  //...
  public void foo() {}
  public void bar() {}
  //...
}

public class Class2 implements ICommonUsage
{
  //...
  public void foo() {}
  public void bar() {}
  //...
}

public class Class3
{
  //...
  private List<ICommonUsage> commonUsedObjects;

  public void commonUsage()
  {
    for ( ICommonUsage item : commonUsedObjects )
    {
      item.foo();
      item.bar();
    }
  }
  //...
}
```

If you want to add an object/interface to a generic list that is not conform with its class (it hasn't the ability to call the methods on it) the compiler log an error message.