# Merge two lists in to maps under one list in java

Tags: java, collections

I have two lists like this:

```
List<Post> posts = Post.findAll();
List<Comment> comments = Comment.findAll();
```

I want to combine these two into one list but with two maps so that when this back to client, it would be one array with two objects with names.

For example output on clientside:

```
Array:[posts:{...}, comments:{...}]
```

How do I achieve this in java?

I tried to add two list to new array but it is not very efficient because I need to loop over complete array on client side:

```
List<Post> posts = Post.findAll();
List<Comment> comments = Comment.findAll();
List listFinal = new ArrayList();
listFinal.addAll(posts);
listFinal.addAll(comments);
return listFinal;
```

Comment: What do you mean list with two maps?

Comment: @Justas List with map1, map2 so the output on clientside would be `Array:[posts:{...}, comments:{...}]`

Comment: see my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055088/another-arraylist-to-another-arraylist-of-different-type/43055261?noredirect=1#comment73195651_43055261

Comment: Why do you need this? I don't see any point in doing that.

Comment: `posts:{...}, comments:{...}` is an associative array, in Java that's a Map.

Comment: so you want a list with two hash maps (post & comments)?

Comment: @pratikpncl Correct!

Comment: @Satyadev does Post and Comment have anything in common? like ID or something?

Comment: @pratikpncl yes username is common

Comment: do you have to use lists? I have an implementation that uses hash maps

Comment: @pratikpncl well I can try if it works

Answer (score 1):

This is my implementation, i generalized for n lists.

```
public static Map<String,Object> mixLists(List<?>...lists){
    Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();

    for (int i = 0;i < lists.length;i++){
        if (!lists[i].isEmpty())
            map.put(lists[i].get(0).getClass().getName(), lists[i]);
    }
    return map;
}
```

The function returns a map [that you can iterate like a List.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-to-efficiently-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-map)

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best solution but you can create a new Object that has `Post` & `Comment` in it. Then add elements with same username form `Post` and `Comment` to it:

```
class PostData {
    Post post;
    Comment comment;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return post.toString() + comment.toString();
    }
}
```

Then create a list of that object:

```
List<PostData> postData = new ArrayList<>();
```